# How to add a check box on Ultrawebgrid?

Tags: c#, checkbox, ultrawebgrid

I have requirement like i want to add a checkbox on my Ultraweb grid.
how can achive this?
I want to add this in the run time i.e row initialization time.
can one help me?

Answer (score 1):

Since the UltraWebGrid is an Infragistics-control, I suggest you look at their forums - they're quite good at providing thorough answers.

A quick googling led me to this page ([link](http://forums.infragistics.com/forums/p/10375/39704.aspx)) on their forums, where they also discuss under which scenarios it is useful.